# Animate flex transitions

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-transitions

So I don't believe this has been answered elsewhere. I have been looking over CSS tricks and also http://n12v.com/css-transition-to-from-auto/ but am not sure if the following is possible.

What I want to do is animate a flex child if it changes width. That width change *could* be triggered from within the child itself. Here is some sample code:

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
}

.flexy {
  transition: all 10s;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flexy" style="background-color:red;">This is some random text</div>
  <div class="flexy" style="background-color:green;">
    <div style="width:300px">Resize this to animate?</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexy" style="background-color:blue;">This is some more random text</div>
</div>
```

So what I want is the flexy boxes to animate to their sizes **and** most importantly if (in say firebug) you change the 300px width to 500px I would want the flexy parent (of the 300px div) to animate too. Is that even possible?

Comment: As far as I know the *only* animatable flex-property is `flex-basis` so this is, possible..but only for *fixed values* but I don't think that's the cas here...is it?

Answer (score 8):

If I understand correctly, you want the Green div to animate a change in "width".

As you say you can't aninate to/from `auto` but you can animate from one defined valued to another.

In thie case we can take advantage of `flex-basis` rather than `width`

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.container>div {
  transition: all 2s;
}

.flexy {
  transition: all 2s;
  flex: 0 0 300px;
  background: green;
}

.flexy:hover {
  flex: 0 0 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="" style="background-color:red;">This is some random text</div>
  <div class="flexy">
    <div style="">Resize this to animate?</div>
  </div>
  <div class="" style="background-color:blue;">This is some more random text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer but unfortunately I might have confused things with the 500px widths. If I adjust (say through javascript) the .flexy element to 320px this will not work. In effect I need as much variable/auto-ness as possible as the columns don't have set widths. I'm not sure its actually possible.